# JSON Parsing Issue in python

Tags: python, json

When I'm trying to parse a JSON dump, I get this attribute error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "Security_Header_Collector.py", line 120, in <module>
            process(sys.argv[-1])
          File "Security_Header_Collector.py", line 67, in process
            server_details = json.load(header_final)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
            return loads(fp.read(),
        AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Script:

```
finalJson[App[0]] = headerJson
            header_final=json.dumps(finalJson,indent=4)
            #print header_final
            #json_data=open(header_final)
            server_details = json.load(header_final)
            with open("Out.txt",'wb') as f :
                    for appid, headers in server_details.iteritems():
                            htypes = [h for h in headers if h in (
                             'content-security-policy', 'x-frame-options',
                            'strict-transport-security', 'x-content-type-options',
                            'x-xss-protection')]
                            headers='{},{}'.format(appid, ','.join(htypes))
                            f.write(headers+'\n')
            f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) returns a JSON formatted string, but [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) expects to get file-like objects, not strings.

Solution: use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) instead of `json.load` in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
header_final=json.dumps(finalJson,indent=4)
```

will give you string,

you have to use `json.loads` to convert string to *json*.

Answer (score 0):

json.load - is used for files / objects
json.loads - is used for the strings or array elements.

You may also think about creating the whole JSON in the form of HEREDOC formate at once and latter apply escaping on it - this way it become easier to validate JSON format.